# Load different .css basing on user-agent - GWT project

Tags: css, gwt, user-agent

I developed a GWT aplication which was initially meant only for Desktop PC browser. Now I decided to make it available also to smartphones and tablets. I created a different .css for each user-agent. Now my question is, how can I decide which of these files to load basing on the type of user-agent? Is this strategy a good one, or there is a better practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To swap implementation according to the user-agent, you can use [deferred binding](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#replacement), which is a built-in GWT feature.

In you module.gwt.xml type something like:

```
<module>
   ...
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.sample.mobilewebapp.FormFactor'/>
  ...
  <!-- Use ClientFactoryImpl by default -->
  <replace-with class="com.google.gwt.sample.mobilewebapp.client.ClientFactoryImpl">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.sample.mobilewebapp.client.ClientFactory"/>
  </replace-with>

  <!-- Use ClientFactoryImplMobile for mobile form factor. -->
  <replace-with class="com.google.gwt.sample.mobilewebapp.client.ClientFactoryImplMobile">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.sample.mobilewebapp.client.ClientFactory"/>
    <when-property-is name="formfactor" value="mobile"/>
  </replace-with>

  <!-- Use ClientFactoryImplTablet for tablet form factor. -->
  <replace-with class="com.google.gwt.sample.mobilewebapp.client.ClientFactoryImplTablet">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.sample.mobilewebapp.client.ClientFactory"/>
    <when-property-is name="formfactor" value="tablet"/>
  </replace-with>

</module>
```

Then just call GWT.create(ClientFactory.class) to get the proper implementation at runtime. For CSS, use a subclass of CSSResource or ClientBundle. [Source is here.](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp/src/com/google/gwt/sample/mobilewebapp/MobileWebApp.gwt.xml?r=10041)

Answer (score 1):

I am using [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) for creating mobile gwt apps.

There is a themeing based on user agent: https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mgwt/ui/client/theme/MGWTThemeBaseThemeStandardImpl.java

In your Bundle you can seperate different css. If you don't use CssResources you may just use the [StyleInjector](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/StyleInjector)

Comment: So if I wanted to use mgwt, I'd have to write a brand new EntryPoint?

Comment: I don't ment to use MGWT. I meant: Take a look, how it was made there.